# react native name of export/render structures

Tags: react-native, render

On react native I have seen 2 ways to do the export/render, what are the name of them, what other export ways are there?

one way:

```
export default function App() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
  </View>
);
}
```

second way:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>MaKo Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is a functional component and the second one is a class component.
Most code use these two ways to export or render.
There have some description on [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).